# HTML: White space below website and does not automatic zoom in during mobile view

Tags: html, css, mobile, layout

So this is my first time trying out html and css. I couldnt manage to get the white space at the bottom of the website to disappear. Here is the html code, images are ommitted for privacy

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d1341f9b7a.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
    <title>Personal Website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="someimage.png" alt="" class="box-img" >
      <h1>My Name</h1>
      <h5>Heading 2</h5>
      <p>Some texts in this paragraph.</p>
      <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

The elements are described in the following css code:

```
@viewport{
    width:device-width;
    height:device-height;
    zoom:1.0;
}   

html{
    height:100%;
    padding-bottom:10%;
}   

/* body{ */
/*   min-height:100%; */
/*   margin: 0; */
/*   padding: 0; */
/*   background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat; */
/*   background-size: 100%; */
/*   overflow:auto; */
/*   padding-bottom:20px; */
/*   /\* border: 1px solid transparent; *\/ */
/* } */
.box{
  width: 450px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic',sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
  overflow:auto;
  height:100%;
}
.box-img{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.box h1{
  font-family: 'Century Gothic',sans-serif;
  font-size: 80px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.box h5{
  font-family: 'Century Gothic',sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
}
.box p{
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic',sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style:italic;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
}
ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.box li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 6px;
  list-style: none;
}
.box li a{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 60px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}
.box li a:hover{
  color: #8b8b8b;
}   

.clearfix::after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**Main points**: So my website is like this: a box element containing img-box and display some headlines and paragraphs.  My photo is displayed in img-box. Body has a background, which is set in `mystyle.css`.  Originally, I had the a background set as the body.

**Issues**: With the background on or off (in current css code, I had it commented out), I still have a white background underneath.  I want my entire box to fit the frame of the browser both in mobile and in desktop version.  In other words, say I open the web page in mobile, it should automatically resize and I should see box nicely fitted without doing any zooming in by hand.

**Attempted solution**: I tried to add the viewport meta name as suggested to hopefully make website mobile friendly and remove white space underneath.  Still, the issue is still there.  This shows up clearly if you put a dark background for body and box.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check with below code, hope it will resolve your query.

```css
@viewport{
    width:device-width;
    height:device-height;
    zoom:1.0;
}   

html{
    height:100%;
    padding-bottom:10%;
}   

/* body{ */
/*   min-height:100%; */
/*   margin: 0; */
/*   padding: 0; */
/*   background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat; */
/*   background-size: 100%; */
/*   overflow:auto; */
/*   padding-bottom:20px; */
/*   /\* border: 1px solid transparent; *\/ */
/* } */
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.box{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 11%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic',sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
  overflow:auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
}
.box-inner {
  
}
.box-img{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.box h1{
  font-family: 'Century Gothic',sans-serif;
  font-size: 80px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.box h5{
  font-family: 'Century Gothic',sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
}
.box p{
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic',sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style:italic;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
}
ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.box li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 6px;
  list-style: none;
}
.box li a{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 60px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}
.box li a:hover{
  color: #8b8b8b;
}   

.clearfix::after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}

@media (max-width:700px){
  .box{
    padding: 6%;
  }
  .box h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d1341f9b7a.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
    <title>Personal Website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-inner">
        <img src="someimage.png" alt="" class="box-img" >
        <h1>My Name</h1>
        <h5>Heading 2</h5>
        <p>Some texts in this paragraph.</p>
        <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!  What does "-webkit-align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;  -webkit-justify-content: center;"  do?

Comment: These are flex properties to make element center from horizontal and vertical for more info please refer: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/